# invalid argument for "--mount" flag: unexpected key 'addr'

Tags: docker, nfs

I want to use docker nfs volume.

What I have tried:

**1. Create a volume first then use it, it's OK**

```
docker volume create --driver local --opt type=nfs --opt o=nfsvers=4,addr=10.192.244.109 --opt device=:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp my1
docker run -it --rm --name nfs-test -v my1:/data alpine sh
```

**2. Directly use volume when `docker run`, it's also OK**

```
docker run -it --rm --name nfs-test --mount type=volume,volume-driver=local,dst=/data,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp,"volume-opt=o=addr=10.192.244.109" alpine sh
```

**The problem happens when I want to specify `nfsvers=4`** in `docker run`:

```
# docker run -it --rm --name nfs-test --mount type=volume,volume-driver=local,dst=/data,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp,"volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=10.192.244.109" alpine sh
invalid argument "type=volume,volume-driver=local,dst=/data,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp,volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,addr=10.192.244.109" for "--mount" flag: unexpected key 'addr' in 'addr=10.192.244.109'
See 'docker run --help'.
```

You could see `Item1` shows we could specify `nfs version` when use nfs volume, while `Item2` shows we could directly use nfs volume within `docker run` without pre-create a volume.

But, how I could specify `nfs version` when directly use `docker run`? What's the correct format here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
--mount 'type=volume,dst=/data,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=nfs,volume-opt=device=:/var/lib/lava/dispatcher/tmp,"volume-opt=o=addr=10.192.244.109,rw,nfsvers=4"'
```

Seems like the argument parser is picky with the quotes.
It is parsed as an extra argument then.
Alternately you can use
`..,volume-opt=o=nfsvers=4,volume-opt=o=addr=10.192.244.109`

Comment: Great, the `single quotes` makes the magic, thanks! Although in my `item2` I no need it, but if add more option, looks we really need that `single quotes`.